# Replace certain characters with an image?

Tags: javascript, replace, blogger

What I'd like to do is have a Javascript code which replaces (S) with a small 16x16 image. I use (S) to link to the source of my information in articles on my site. It looks a little unprofessional and messy, and I was wondering if there is a way (even without JS) to get my blog to automatically replace every occurrence of (S) in my post with either a 16x16 image or a character such as that one used on Wikipedia to show the link opens in a new tab.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: I work with Blogger by the way. Manually putting in a HTML code is also a no-no as there are other writers on the blog who are pretty much computer illiterate.

Comment: If they can type "(S)" they can type "<span class="external"></span>", and all you need is the appropriate CSS entry.

Comment: you can directly use img tag eg. text <img src=''> text.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an editor in a page I'm playing with. It updates as you type, showing a live preview of how the post will look - all client-side, no ajax, lightening fast.

I call this function in response to keyup an change events.

```
var content;

function byId(e) {return document.getElementById(e);}

function onPreview()
{
    var modifiedStr, re;

    var textArea = byId("threadText");
    var threadTextOrig = textArea.value;
    content = textArea;

    re = new RegExp("\n", "g");
    var modifiedStr = threadTextOrig.replace(re, "<br>");

    re = new RegExp(":wtf:", "g");
    modifiedStr = modifiedStr.replace(re, '<img src="img/smiley_WTF.gif" align="top" alt="WTF | :WTF:">');

    re = new RegExp(":\\)", "g");
    modifiedStr = modifiedStr.replace(re, '<img src="img/smiley_smile.gif" align="top" alt="Smile | :)">');

    re = new RegExp(":-D", "g");
    modifiedStr = modifiedStr.replace(re, '<img src="img/smiley_biggrin.gif" align="top" alt="Big Grin | :-D">');

    var tgt = byId(previewDiv);
    previewDiv.innerHTML = modifiedStr;

    var tgt = byId('previewTitle');

    var src = byId('title');
    var srcVal = src.value;
    tgt.innerHTML = "<strong>" + srcVal + "</strong>";
}
```

**html**

```
<input name="title" id="title" value="Waiting for approval" style="width:100%" onchange="onPreview();" onkeyup="onPreview();" onmouseup="onPreview()">
<textarea rows="10" cols="80" id="threadText" name="threadText" onchange="onPreview();" onkeyup="onPreview();" onmouseup="onPreview()"></textarea>
```